# Language translation in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, internationalization, iphone

I am trying to build an app which consists of a label which displays the text in English by default. The user gets a list to select his/her language and after selecting the language, the text changes to that particular language. Any idea as to how to do it? I had tried

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", @"en", @"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with :

[`-[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/localizedStringForKey%3avalue%3atable%3a)

There is a small sample in the docs. Basically what you need to do is create a MyTable.strings file with the localizations you need. Create one file per language you need.
Then do:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *localizedString = [bundle localizedStringForKey:@"TheKeyYouWantToLocalize"]
                                                    value:@"TheDefaultValue" 
                                                    table:@"MyTable"];
```

This method will look for the key: `@"TheKeyYouWantToLocalize"` in *MyTable.strings* file , if its is found then it will return that otherwise it will return `@"TheDefaultValue"`

FYI, This is the same process the system uses when localizing an app. (Heard of `NSLocalizedString` ?) but now you have to do it manually since you are asking the user the language to show and not relying in the system language.

Comment: Is there any other way than localizing files.